# Mongoose does not connect to local database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Previously I tried to connect it by setting dbURI to the URI that mongo gives you upon clicking "connect application" and it did not work, later I tried to set up a local database with mongoDB, where i downloaded it, set it up and all the like. I created the data/db folder as well and i can open up an empty database upon typing the link in compass. Regardless of all of that, mongoose still doesn't allow me to connect to the database, giving me this error:

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\tests\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:467:30)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (D:\tests\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (D:\tests\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
}
```

Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CPD = require("./database/log");

// express
const app = express();

// database
const dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local'

mongoose.connect(dbURI).then((res) => console.log("success")).catch((err) => console.log(err))


//serverstuff
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome!')

})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Database `local` is a Mongo internal database (you should not use it for your application data) and it exist only when you have a [Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/replication/). Apart from that, it looks like you missed username/password.

Answer (score 0):

try using '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'

```
const dbURI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local'
```